# How to compile 32-bit executable in QT Creator on Mac OS Lion

Tags: macos, flash, qt, qt-creator

As mentioned in this bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84983, the 64-bit executable compiled by QT creator 4.7.4 or 4.8.0 on Mac OS 10.6 will crash or show no flash content when viewing a page with flash content.

However, I don't see any option to compile 32-bit executable in QT 4.8.0 for Mac. The only available toolchain choices are 64bit gcc and 64-bit clang. Although 32-bit toolchains are detected, they are not available as a choice. Perhaps, QT 4.8 only shipped 64-bit libraries so that we have to compile 64-bit executables?

Do I have to rebuild the QT source code to get 32-bit QT for Mac? Has anyone done it before?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to build it from source to get 32-bit libraries. The pre-build Qt libraries are only in 64-bit.

Just follow the building [steps](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/install-mac.html) and add -arch i386 to your configure options.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use ./configure -universal option for universal support

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configure command to build a 32 bit only version of QT

```
./configure -platform macx-clang-32
```

This following command will install QT to /usr/local/Qt-x.y.z

```
sudo make install
```

Then add a new tool chain using clang-32 and your newly installed QT